# I can't import xml.dom.minidom in PyCharm. What could I Try?

Tags: python, xml, pycharm, python-import, minidom

I'm trying to import xml.dom.minidom but pycharm doesn't find it, altough it finds xml.entree / xml.parser / xml.sax.

The rest of the standart libraries work all fine.
The xml file (beispiel.xml) shouldn't be the problem, because it hasn't "xml" in the name.

```
    from xml.dom import minidom

    document = minidom.parse("beispiel.xml")

    wanted_info = input("Which prduct do you want to see?")

    product_list = document.getElementsByTagName(wanted_info)

    for product in product_list:

        for value in product.childNodes:
            if value.nodeType == minidom.Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
                print(value.tagName + ":" + value.firstChild.data)
        print("\n")
```

I'm not shure, what it could be. It could be, because i have installed python in D:... and pycharm in C:... but i dont think that's the problem.

[image: Python and Pycharme project locations]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced the same problem after upgrading to 2020.1. The problem is already reported in the [Pycharm issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-41791).

There they propose the following workaround until the issue is fixed:

> Replace xml directory in `<INSTALLATION_FOLDER>\plugins\python(-ce)\helpers\typeshed\stdlib\2and3\` with `xml` from https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/master/stdlib/2and3/xml

On my machine this solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

My recommendation is to just put the following around the imports until Pycharm fixes the bug.

```
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
from xml.dom.minidom import Document
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
from xml.dom.minidom import Element
```

Answer (score 1):

Now it is fixed. I am using 2021.1